# SAP GUI Run Time Error 1000 Logon connection entry not found

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Using following code to login to SAP GUI.

```
   Sub Logontrial()
     
    Dim SapGuiApp As Object
    Dim oConnection As Object
    Dim session As Object
    Dim SAPCon As Object, SAPSesi As Object
    Dim SAPGUIAuto As Object, SAPApp As Object
    Dim sapConnection As Object
    
    If SapGuiApp Is Nothing Then
        Set SapGuiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
    End If
    If oConnection Is Nothing Then
        Set oConnection = SapGuiApp.OpenConnection("Description of connection")
    End If
    If SAPSesi Is Nothing Then
       Set SAPSesi = oConnection.Children(0)
    End If
        
     sapConnection.Client = "011"
     sapConnection.User = "TEST123"
     sapConnection.Password = "XXXX"
     sapConnection.Language = "EN"
      
    End Sub
```

I get this error:

> Run Time Error '1000'. SAP logon connection entry not found.

I have done ample research in this subject, still no success. Corrections to this code will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont work with SAP but see if [THIS](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2142369) helps?

Comment: In `SapGuiApp.OpenConnection("Description of connection")` the `Description of connection` must exactly match the `Name` of the SAP connection as shown in Logon Pad.

Answer (score 0):

This Question was resolved for me by @AxelRichter's comment above:

> In SapGuiApp.OpenConnection("Description of connection") the Description of connection must exactly match the Name of the SAP connection as shown in Logon Pad.

Answer (score 0):

NAME NAME NAME is the stuff. 
I had the same issue, all time long I had the SID (3 CHARACTER) going on working on my macro, then stopped working, then changed to the NAME oft he connection (DESCRIPTION OF THE CONNECTION) and it worked. Thanks to Axel Richter for his comment.